# Javascript: Call parent html method from child html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an html page (call it "primary") which calls child html pages. To start with,  it calls the child "defaultpage". When the user is done reading a child page, I want a button to replace the page with "defaultpage" again. I'm very new to javascript, so what I've tried to do is to create a method on the "primary" html:

```
function loader(webpage){
    document.getElementById("mainarea").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data='+webpage+'>
</object>';}
```

This part works fine and loads the child htmls properly. But when I naively try to call the method again from the child html via

```
<button onclick='parent.loader("defaultpage.html")'>Return</button>
```

it doesn't. If I place the button on "primary" with `loader` instead of `parent.loader` it works, but I want the button to belong to the child so that users scroll down to it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Nothing about this is “fine”, IMHO, you are basically recreating all the accessibility problems sites build on frames or iframes had, only with `object`. This is so outdated and flawed as an approach already, I don’t think you should waste any further time on pursuing this in the first place.

Comment: Seconding @CBroe's comment here - this isn't a good approach.  I appreciate that you're new to JavaScript, and it can often be confusing to know where to start even if you have a good idea as to what it is you want to achieve.  IMO I think you should take a look a Single Page Applications (SPAs), and the various frameworks that exist for solving this problem.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you both for your comments. Is there a specific framework I should look into, one that won't become obsolete in a couple of years?